# Using angular to extract specific Json data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, angularjs-ng-repeat

Can someone please point out where I am making a mistake.

Its a very simple application that is meant to print out the "name" field in and array of Json objects, Which is done via the line :

`{{ctrl.contact[0].results[0].name.first}}` or
`{{ctrl.contact[1].results[0].name.first}}`

(which in itself seems very convoluted)

I cannot get it to print out the name of each Json block individually by loop and here is what i have tried :

```
        <div ng-repeat="i in ctrl.contact">
            <span>{{ctrl.contact[i].results[0].name.first}}</span>
        </div>
```

Im confident after spending a few hours tweaking and editing that my angular set up (app, controller etc) is fine.

code snippet below :

```html
<html ng-app="ContactAppApp">
<head>
  <title>My Contact App</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.5/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <div ng-controller="ContactAppController as ctrl">
             
             <h1>{{ctrl.test}}</h1>
            
            <div ng-repeat="i in ctrl.contact">
                <span>{{ctrl.contact[0].results[0].name.first}}</span>
            </div>
            
        </div>
        
    </div>
</body>

<script>
    
    var app = angular.module("ContactAppApp", [])
    app.controller("ContactAppController", ContactAppController);
    
    function ContactAppController() {
       
       this.test = "This text is generated by Angular";
        
        this.contact = [
            {
                "results": [
                    {
                        "gender": "male",
                        "name": {
                            "title": "mr",
                            "first": "tony",
                            "last": "cruz"
                        },
                        "location": {
                            "street": "9813 north road",
                            "city": "edinburgh",
                            "state": "humberside",
                            "postcode": "E84 4YD"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "results": [
                    {
                        "gender": "male",
                        "name": {
                            "title": "mr",
                            "first": "Jack",
                            "last": "cruz"
                        },
                        "location": {
                            "street": "9813 north road",
                            "city": "edinburgh",
                            "state": "humberside",
                            "postcode": "E84 4YD"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }

</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
<div ng-repeat="i in ctrl.contact">
    <span>{{i.results[0].name.first}}</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Great. Worked, thanks a lot. So what does i refer to ? Is it the object held in the current iteration ? it doesnt seem to be a loop counter/number based on the answer

Comment: `i` refers to the current object. You can use `ng-repeat="(i, contact) in ctrl.contact"` syntax and in such case `i` will refer to the current index. Also you can simply use special keyword `$index` together with [`ngRepeat`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) directive.

Comment: Correct, in this case `i` is a representation of each element of the array `ctrl.contact`

Answer (score 0):

I would set up your array a little differently. Try something like this:

```
this.contact = {
    "results": [
          {
            "gender": "male",
            "name": {
                "title": "mr",
                "first": "tony",
                "last": "cruz"
            },
            "location": {
                "street": "9813 north road",
                "city": "edinburgh",
                "state": "humberside",
                "postcode": "E84 4YD"
            }
        },
        {
              "gender": "male",
              "name": {
                  "title": "mr",
                  "first": "Jack",
                  "last": "cruz"
              },
              "location": {
                  "street": "9813 north road",
                  "city": "edinburgh",
                  "state": "humberside",
                  "postcode": "E84 4YD"
              }
         }
    ]
}
```

Then in your ng-repeat, try something like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in contact.results">
    <span>{{item.name.first}} {{$index}}</span>
</div>
```

If you are trying to track the index of the item in array, use $index, not i.